# Xcode search Controller - show search bar at the start (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to show the search engine when loading the controller.

I do not mean:

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

I want to hide the search engine while scrolling.
I only want to show it once at the start,
how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: So you want, show search bar at the start, but when you scroll the search bar hides?

Comment: What about putting the search bar in a scroll view controller with the table view?

Comment: David Kadlcek - Yes!. Harcker - yes my controller is a Table View

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

            performTaskAfterDealy(1, {
                self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
            })
```

Work for me :)

ps:

```
func performTaskAfterDealy(_ timeInteval: TimeInterval, _ task:@escaping () -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: (.now() + timeInteval)) {
            task()
        }
    }
```